# Android Toolbar menu items never shows, but goes into overflow

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement the toolbar that Android made available in v21 with a menu where the menu items are set to show "ifroom", but the menu items always collapses into the overflow. They also collapses into the overflow if the menu items are set to show "always".

I hope someone can point out what needs to changed to make it behave correct. I would like to find a solution which doesn't do it using appcompat to achieve it, as I can see most other solutions does.

Below I have attached my toolbar layout, menu layout and screenshoot of how it looks in the simulator, as well as the main kotlin file creating the toolbar.

Screenshoot from emulator

[image]

toolbar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miCompose"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_compose"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

mainActivity.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    val TAG: String = "MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myToolbar = findViewById<View>(R.id.my_toolbar) as Toolbar
        myToolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_main)
        myToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById<View>(R.id.my_toolbar) as Toolbar` is useless, use just `findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.my_toolbar)`

Comment: tried the change, but I don't see a difference in behavior whether I do it one way or the other.

Comment: It isn't about the question. Just avoid an extra cast

Comment: understod, I will adopt your suggestion

Comment: You want to display both menu always visible. Right?

Comment: No, I want to display the Menu options if there is room for them. The answer from RobCo did the trick for me. The menu options are now shown if there is room for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using all Android APIs, not support library.
So try using `android` instead of `app`:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```